# French Auxiliary Selection. Theoretical explanations?

Tags: cross-linguistic, french, theoretical-linguistics, generative-grammar, auxiliary-verbs

I've heard that Generative Approaches trying to explain Auxiliary Selection are mostly focused in Italian, because its a language which intransitive verbs respond pretty well  to unaccusativity diagnostics. It seems that other languages, like French, don't respond so clearly to the inacusative split.

I would like to know if you can tell me about papers or theories that would focus in Auxiliary Selection in French, cause what I have found so far (appart from Legendre and Sorace) is mostly based in Italian and Dutch.

Thank you